# Where is localhost folder located in Mac or Mac OS X?

Tags: php, macos, eclipse-pdt

I just started developing PHP projects on my mac (using PDT) and was wondering where localhost is located? How does Mac OS X serve websites, I haven't changed any settings during the installation of PDT.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

There are actually two place where mac os x serves websites by default:

1. /Library/WebServer/Documents --> http://localhost
2. ~/Sites --> http://localhost/~user/

Comment: I don't know how I did this, but I have both of these folders and 2nd one is the working one, but the httpd.conf file is under /etc/apache2 and ServerRoot there shows the first folder. How can I find the httpd.conf file the server is using?

Comment: I have edited httpd.conf under /etc/apache2 and changed DocumentRoot and Directory to same folder /Users/{username}/Sites and everything is "It Works!" now :) I am not deleting these comments, hoping this may help someone. :)

Answer (score 21):

## For posterity

I never use PHP so I completely forgot where apache was installed on my mac as it was running on port 8080 mocking me, installed in a **non-standard path**. After giving up on the internet, I tried this...

```
httpd -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

Because httpd was running it produced the httpd.config path and then the clouds parted and the sun shown brightly on my face. **Victory!** as within it lies the path to localhost.

```
ServerRoot "/your/path"
```

Mac OS 12 root*

```
/usr/local/var/www
```

*credit [@cong-lb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8360673/cong-lb)

Comment: ServerRoot actually specifies the webserver's executable directory. One should actually look for "DocumentRoot" wherein you can find the path for the files that are being served by the Apache Server.

Comment: @SachinKhosla would be good to provide a script that would locate DocumentRoot. Maybe grep 'DocumentRoot' / -rli ?

Comment: In macos 12, the path has changed. It worked for me. My path is /usr/local/var/www

Answer (score 17):

The default Apache root folder (localhost/) is /Library/WebServer/Documents

Also, make sure you have the PHP5 module loaded in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use apachectl to start or stop, then you can find it with this command

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG
```

Comment: This is it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Actually in newer Osx os's, this is stored in `/Library/WebServer/Documents/`

The .en file is just an html file, but it needs special permissions to change, so I just made a folder for my stuff and then accessed it by
`user.local/Folder/file.html`

Answer (score 4):

I realized you need to start service first.

1. Start apache service
   `sudo apachectl start`
2. Test in browser by hitting localhost
   You should get "**It works**" message in the browser
3. Serve your files inside `/Library/WebServer/Documents` folder. Make directories if necessary.

**Important: Notice in step 3 that it is `/Library` and not `~/Library`**

> Tested in MacOS 11.2.3 Big Sur

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as a "localhost" folder; the word "localhost" is an alias for your local computer. The document root for your apache server, by default, is "Sites" in your home directory.

Comment: That's not the root folder. Root is `http://localhost/`. The folder you're refering to is located at `http://localhost/~User/`.

Comment: +1 for the "localhost" hate, even though ~/Sites is only half the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Macintosh HD/Library/WebServer/Documents

Macintosh HD is the name of your HD

If you can't find it: Open Finder > click "Go" at the very top > Computer > Your HD should be there. You can drag and drop the HD to favorites on the left.

Answer (score -3):

open the 'Finder' in Mac and **Command+Shift+G** and type in the path:/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs. path will open then create/paste your web page/application then check it on the browser.

Answer (score -12):

Applications -> XAMPP -> htdocs This is the place where you should put your files for the website you're building.