# actionscript3 is not getting the response from php

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I was just doing a test, but i couldn't get even the test to work.
I just want to run a php that returns the date to flash, but it returns the entire code instead. I don't know what i am doing wrong

Here is my as3 code:

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;

var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
ldr.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("config_flash.php");
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
ldr.load(req);

function onLoaded(evt:Event){
    trace(evt.target.data)
}
```

I also tried using URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT and URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES
I also tried using URLRequestMethod.GET

Now the php:

```
<?php
    print "&serverDate=".date(j); 
?>
```

the only output I have no matter what I try is the code itself:

```
<?php
    print "&serverDate=".date(j); 
?>
```

Somebody can see what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your PHP file located? Is it on a local server or what?

Comment: heyYO is right. You probably are not running the file on a server like a local server or webhost

Comment: the file is located in the same folder of the .fla and the .swf

Comment: @FredericoPeres that won't work. It needs to be run on a web server. Even localhost will work

Comment: @Frederico PHP is a server side language

Comment: ok, i started an Apache 2.2 local web server. But the problem persists. I just changed the line:
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("config_flash.php");
to:
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/config_flash.php");

Answer (score 0):

**Change your code to the following**

```
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
ldr.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/flashtests/config_flash.php");
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
ldr.load(req);

function onLoaded(evt:Event){
    trace(evt.target.data)
}
```

Here is the catch, you'll need to enable your Mac / Linux machines HTTP WebServer, and setup the directory where localhost resides.

Here is a SO article for finding localhost on your ***Mac*** and there are several out there for your Windows machine depending on version.

[Where is localhost folder located in Mac or Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365055/where-is-localhost-folder-located-in-macbook)

cd Library/WebServer/Documents/
On a Mac, PHP is installed by default and is likely to be located in

```
/usr/lib/php
```

**test your php script in the command line just to be sure**

```
php http://localhost/flashtests/config_flash.php
```

Now go back and run the flash document and run it. Your onLoadedEvent should be called if your **http server is enabled** and **php is installed** on the machine.